# Show multiple sheet using googlescript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I want to retrieve a data from my google sheet, using this code and I want to check morethan 1 sheetname in the sametime, for example "Example1" and "Example2".

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate()
  .setTitle("Project 1")
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){ 
  var concat = formObject.searchtext.toString().toLowerCase()+formObject.searchtext2;
  var result = "";
  if(concat){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(concat);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS ;
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1-BLridljB9evNODil4HTI904jZNEi-h3O4FhY_qw9VQ'; //** CHANGE !!!!
  var sheetName = "Example1"
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~[f[6]].indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push([ f[1],f[2],  '<a target="_blank" href=' + f[3] + '>' + f[5] + '</a>'  ,f[4] ]);
    }
  });
                                           
  return ar;
};
```

Oh.. at first I already run and edit this code too, using my personal Id but it doesnt show anything, it says Data Not Found, for more information I had 6 columns in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) removing all the code that is not relevant to the specific problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f[6].toString().indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push([ f[1],f[2],  '<a target="_blank" href=' + f[3] + '>' + f[5] + '</a>'  ,f[4] ]);
    }
  });
```

I tested it this way:

```
function search(searchtext='xxx'){
  //var spreadsheetId   = '1-BLridljB9evNODil4HTI904jZNEi-h3O4FhY_qw9VQ'; //** CHANGE !!!!
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f[6].toString().indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push([ f[1],f[2],  '<a target="_blank" href=' + f[3] + '>' + f[5] + '</a>'  ,f[4] ]);
    }
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ar));                                        
  //return ar;
};
```

It work okay for me

Now for multiple sheets

```
function search(searchtext = 'xxx') {
  let ar = [];
  //var spreadsheetId   = '1-BLridljB9evNODil4HTI904jZNEi-h3O4FhY_qw9VQ'; //** CHANGE !!!!
  const names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  names.forEach((name) => {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(name).getDataRange();
    var data = range.getValues();
    data.forEach(function (f) {
      if (~f[6].toString().indexOf(searchtext)) {
        ar.push([f[1], f[2], '<a target="_blank" href=' + f[3] + '>' + f[5] + '</a>', f[4]], name);
      }
    });
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ar));
  //return ar;
};
```

Comment: I try to put my spreadsheetId on those line, but it doesn't show anything

`href= 1AtcJI2zAAxCXa0E540nWF1IOMUH0RRxH1BWE_8nB4LU'`

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  How do you put a spreadsheet on a line?